# Using CSS how do I prevent my click events from being intercepted by elements on top?

Tags: css

I have a div that overlaps another one that I want to click on. I want to allow the click to go through to the bottom div. I don't want to use JS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

> pointer-events:none;

<sub>The only problem with this is [Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)</sub>

Comment: But then you disable clicking in the entire `div`.

Answer (score 4):

Two options- Use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) or set `z-index` to `0`. These should be added in the stylesheet to the element you don't want to be clicked.

The first option makes it so that it can't be the target of mouse events. However, even if you click it outside of the overlapped area, it still won't work. With the second option, it will work outside the overlapped area.

Comment: @Danko True, but the alternative is to disable the div from being clicked alltogether.